# why i am getting empty response text in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

below is my code fo ajax which sends a string data via post method, the request is successful but I get an empty response. I had checked the readystate and status both are proper and the php file is in the same directory.

```
function getData(str)
        {   
            if (str == "")
            {
            } else
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {   

                   var dat = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else
                {   

                    dat = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                 dat.open("POST","userdat.php",true);

                dat.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                dat.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {    
                    if (dat.readyState == 4 && dat.status == 200)
                    {   
                         alert(dat.responseText);
                         $('#dataReT').text(dat.responseText);
                    }
                }

                dat.send("userid=" + str);

            }

        }
```

content of my php file:

```
<?php
$id=$_REQUEST['userid'];
echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Where do you send the value that should be in $_REQUEST['userid']?

Comment: what is the value of $id before you echo it?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` to check if you're actually getting any data to your PHP.-file. (I recommend using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` to make the code more self explanatory).

Comment: I  sent the value via post method in ajax @Glubus

Comment: nothing @Dymen1

Comment: didn't make any difference, I guess the PHP file is not getting the data. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @SamuelForestier than your code is running as expected right?

Comment: What doesn't make any difference? Did you `var_dump($_POST)` to see what it contains? Changing from $_REQUEST to $_POST wasn't a solution, it was just a recommendation.

Comment: When you say _" the request is successful"_, did you determine that through the network tab in your browsers developer console? If not, check what the browser actually sends and what the actual response is.

Answer (score 0):

there is no userid in $_REQUEST. Try to add this to your php file:

```
if(array_key_exists('userid',$_REQUEST)) { 
   echo $_REQUEST['userid']; 
} else { 
   echo 'no userid.';
}
```

You may send userid value from your javascript file

Comment: I did as you have suggested, I am still getting an empty response.